# How big is the Geth Fast Node Currently?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, contract-invocation, etherscan, geth-debugging

I am trying to embark on getting all the contract addresses pulled from the Ethereum blockchain. From what I read, a fast node is all that is required for this (getting blocks->txns->contractAddress using web3 on an IPC node).

The problem is, I have a computer with only 149.9 GB available. [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/chart2/chaindatasizefast) puts it at 132 GB as of Feb 2019. Does anyone have a more recent statistic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer at [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chaindefault). It is currently ~173GB.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael, it should be fixed now.